# React Native APK crashing in MI mobile

Tags: android, react-native

I am building debug APK in JDK 8 environment and manage to run on Samsung device but not able to run on MI mobiles. App keeps getting crashed after showing splash screen.
Below are the screenshots of the error which I am getting from MI mobile.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `notificationListener()` function is not available through `this`

Comment: this issue is not coming when running an apk on samsung device

Comment: Maybe you don`t have permission?